# global variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery is it possible to create a function that sets a variable which I can then access in another function. i.e. I need a global variable that can be accessed anywhere on the page.

Examples

```
$.fn.getRedemptionID = function(){
  var myVar = data.DATA[0].item1;
}
```

Comment: Define your variable outside of the scope of the functions and it's global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Global variables are bad.

2) Yes:

```
// explicit global (preferred)
$.fn.getRedemptionID = function(){
  window.myVar = data.DATA[0].item1;
}

// implicit global
$.fn.getRedemptionID = function(){
  myVar = data.DATA[0].item1;
}
```

Comment: Global variables are bad < why?

Comment: @Spike I will allow someone much smarter than myself to answer: http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2007/10/respecting-javascript-global-namespace.html

Comment: @Spike: Because it is all-too-easy to have different libraries and the like using the same names, and if they're all global they'll clash. Worse, the resulting bugs are a *nightmare* to find because they rely on the interactions of two supposedly-independent things.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this :

```
var myGlobalVar = null;

$.fn.getRedemptionID = function(){
  myGlobalVar = data.DATA[0].item1;
}
```

Then you can access myGlobalVar everywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is still JavaScript, and can still be used like JavaScript. I.e. if you declare something outside of any block, it is global and can be accessed anywhere.

E.g.

```
var global = 42;
$(document).ready(function() {
    global = $('#something').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use closure, to save your variable value in the following manner:

```
var application = (function(){
    var my_var;

    return {
        get_var: function(){
            return my_var;
        },
        set_var: function(value){
            my_var = value;
        }
    }
})();

application.set_var(34);
application.get_var;
```

It's better than using Global variables.